# Break continuous loop with key

Tags: java

How do I break an infinity loop, like this one:

```
while(true){

    if(???){
         break;
    }
}
```

Whitout interrupting it every time it loops and ask for input? The loop has to loop continuous until the user breaks it.

EDIT

I want to break it with a key input.

Comment: You can't interrupt a program without interrupting it.

Comment: How are you thinking you're going to be able to detect "a key input" without checking for it?

Comment: I mean that I do not want to interrupt the loop every time it loops, I do not want the loop to wait for either a continue key or a break key, I just want to interrupt the ongoing loop with a key.

Comment: @theva I am not sure, if it is this what you are looking for, but I think, you might want to check for user input on a different thread. You'll have to introduce some kind of common flag to break the loop, then. Like a volatile boolean.

Comment: Some threading will be needed to catch the user input, but as mentioned before you need to check for it.

Comment: How about telling us what you're trying to do, and we'll tell you a suitable solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the cycle in a separate thread.

```
import java.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                int cnt = 0;

                                while (true) {
                                        System.out.println(cnt);
                                        ++cnt;
                                }
                        }
                });

                t.start();
                System.in.read();
                t.stop();
        }
}
```

Let's analyze it line by line; first the imports:

```
import java.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
```

Then we need to declare that **main** throws IOException, because we'll be dealing with IO calls; a better option is obviously to correctly handle exceptions, but this is just a simple test.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

Then we create a thread which executes an infinite cycle; we will not be doing IO calls from this thread. The thread is not started until we call **Thread.start()**, and will run until we call **Thread.stop()**.

```
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                int cnt = 0;

                                while (true) {
                                        System.out.println(cnt);
                                        ++cnt;
                                }
                        }
                });
```

Now we start the thread; the lines after this call will keep executing concurrently with the thread, so we will be able to wait for user input and stop the thread.

```
                t.start();
                System.in.read();
                t.stop();
        }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, great! The only thing is that java give a notice about Thread.stop is deprecated, but it works!

Comment: You are welcome! It looks like the answer was downvoted by someone who didn't care to provide an explanation; I believe that it is due to the fact the solution I provided is a typical instance of asynchronous cancellation, and **stop** is actually deprecated in Java. Usually you should use synchronization and thread shared variables in order to orchestrate the termination of a thread and precisely choose the right moment at which it should be terminated. I cannot guarantee the correctness of Francis' answer and I haven't tested it but you should have a look at it to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to use a flag controlled by another thread.  You could do something like this:

```
private volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

public synchronized void stopRunning() {
    keepRunning = false;
}

public void someProcess() {
    new Thread() { 
        public void run() { 
            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                keepWaiting = true;
                while(keepWaiting) {
                    String userInput = scanner.next();
                    if("s".equals(userInput)) {
                        stopRunning();
                        keepWaiting = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }.start();

    while(keepRunning){
        doWork();
    }
}
```

The loop should keep running until the user enters "s".  Of course it's a very basic implementation but you get the idea.

Also, you don't really need the "stopRunning()" method, the thread could access the flag directly, but you would need it if you wanted to run the thread from somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use this.

```
boolean doLoop = true;

while(doLoop){

    if(userTerminates()){ //user terminates it?
         doLoop = false;
    }
}

private boolean userTerminates(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //If you want that user terminates it with 'c' char
    return scanner.nextLine().equals("c");
}
```

Comment: No such thing as `bool` in Java.

Comment: Assume there exist `bool` in Java, how this answers the question?

Comment: @Vallentin  come on dude!! It's boolean data type

Comment: Why should this be better?

Comment: Because it is self-commented.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, but if the OP doesn't know that `bool` is the same as `boolean` the code won't help the OP at all.

Comment: If the OP doesn't know that, they probably shouldn't be copy pasting things from here. SO intends to help programmers, not just about anybody who would copy paste and be stumped on a typo by someone who answered.

Comment: To get back on topic: `userTerminates` is blocking, right? Which is what the OP does *not* want. Threading is needed here, I think.